# Como obtener ultimo id insertado en laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

estoy tratando obtener el ultimo id insertado, ay probé con el metodo latest y el metodo last

`$ultimo = Reporte::latest('id_reporte')->first();`
y lo que obtengo es los siguiente.
 String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'folio' at row 1.

Tambien intente con

```
$ultimo = Reporte::get('id_reporte')->last();
```

y me da un array  con {"id_reporte":3}

Trato de insertar de la siguiente forma

```
$reporte = new Reporte ([

        'asunto'        =>  $request->get('asunto'),
        'descripcion'   =>  $request->get('descripcion'),
        'depto_area'   =>  $request->get('departamento'),
        'ubicacion'     =>  $request->get('ubicacion'),
        'folio'         =>  $ultimo+1.'-REPQJ',
        'tipo_reporte'  =>  'QUEJA',
        'fecha'         =>  $request->get('datetimepicker1'),
        'id'            =>  $user
    ]);

    $reporte->save();
```

Comment: @Aprendiz hola, el id_reporte es el identificador de la tabla reportes y quiero obtener el ultimo id para poder cuando registre un nuevo reporte

Comment: @Aprendiz el tipo de dato es $table->bigIncrements('id_reporte');

Comment: así es, el error que me muestra es que me arroja como array cuando introduzco esta linea de código `$ultimo = Reporte::get('id_reporte')->last();` y literalmente inserta en la bd de esa forma {"id_reporte":3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu primer forma de obtener el **`id`** debería funcionar solo que para obtener como valor únicamente el entero y poderlo guardar necesitas una sintaxis de esta forma:

```
$data = Model::latest()->first()->id;
```

- Es decir al final encadenas que acceda a la propiedad que es la única que te interesa obtener, para evitar que te muestre una estructura mas compleja

O siguiendo la otra consulta que tienes la podemos dejar así:

```
$data = Model::all()->last()->id;
```

- Es decir nuevamente obtenemos todos los registro esta vez por medio del método **`all`** Después leemos el último valor de la colección con el método **`last`**
- De ese nuevo conjunto de resultados solo queremos el **`id`** por eso otra vez encadenamos el acceso a dicha propiedad

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudaste bastante si funcionó